# How to detect if a link, inside a UITextView has been clicked, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented what I think is the function from UITextViewDelegate, which deals with URLs being tapped in a UITextView, however the functions now being called in my code.

This is the function I have used from the delegate.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL!, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

println("Link Selected!")

}
```

However I have used breakpoints and the code isn't even being accessed at runtime?
Is this the correct function or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that the class implementing the delegate protocol is set as the delegate for the `UITextView`.

```
self.textView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Oh god how did I forget this, feel like such an idiot. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Your class may look something like :

```
class MyClass: UITextViewDelegate {
     @IBoutet weak var aTextView: UITextView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                aTextView.delegate = self 
        }

       // Delegate
       func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

                // User click on a link in a textview
                print("Link Selected!")

               // True => User can click on the URL Ling (otherwise return false)
                return true
       }
```

}